# Cucumber+Devise routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, devise

having trouble with testing devise sign up on Cucumber. After "Sign Up" click
it shows 
**uninitialized constant User::ArticlesController (ActionController::RoutingError)**
I suppose that's because right after Sign up, devise redirects logged user to Articles page and but it's not under namespace User. Because I test user it put everything under this namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Devise howto](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in) says you can route to something not under the User namespace by naming a user_route path:

```
match 'my/dashboard' => 'my/dashboard#index', :as => 'user_root'
```

So it sounds like you can do something like:

```
match 'articles' => 'articles#index', :as => 'user_root'
```